# C# & C++ checksum calculation

Tags: c#, c++, struct, checksum

I need your help with calculating checksum in C#. Code below is for application writen in C++. App is receiving packets from UDP. This is part of code where is receive and checksum calculation.

```
struct OPtoLSs {BlockReceivedS hdr; char data[0x100];}; //struct for received data
OPtoLSs mCKr;

#define hdrR mCKr.hdr.OPhdr
#define dataR mCKr.data

int const retHdr = recvfrom(sock, (char*)&hdrR, sizeof(hdrR), 0, (sockaddr*)(&from), &len);
int const retDat = recvfrom(sock, (char*)&dataR, hdrR.Length, 0, (sockaddr*)(&from), &len);
for(unsigned _int16 *p = (unsigned _int16*)&mCKr; p < (unsigned _int16*)&mCKr + ((retHdr+retDat)/2); p++)
{
   ChkSum=(_int16)((*p+ChkSum)&0xffff);
}
assert_hard(ChkSum==0xffff);
```

I need to get right calculation for checksum in C#. I used code below, but when I send any msg from C# side to C++ side, it throws this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwSeY.jpg). Please can somebody help with this calculation in C# ? Thanks for all your responses.

```
// mCKr.hdr.OPhdr equivalent
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi, Size = 12)]
 public struct OPpacketHdrS
 {
      public UInt32 packetMark;
      public UInt32 OPpacketID;       
      public UInt16 ChKSum
      {
          get
          {
              UInt16 accumulator = 0;
              unsafe
              {
                  fixed (OPpacketHdrS* x = &this)
                  {
                      for (UInt16* p = (UInt16*)x; p < x + 1; ++p)
                      {
                          accumulator += *p;
                      }
                  }
              }
              return accumulator;
          }
      }

      public UInt16 Length;    
}
// mCKr.data equivalent
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Size = 20)]
 public struct CommandKeyS
 {
      public OPpacketHdrS OPhdr;
      public mHdr Hdr; // Hdr.ID=CommandKeyR
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
      public UInt16 cmdKey, unused;
 }
```

Comment: What is the checksum worth if it must be 0xffff every time? (`assert_hard(ChkSum==0xffff);`)

Comment: If i understand your question right..then in debug ouput i got 36750..and with every sended msg this number is incremented by one

Comment: Your code requires the checksum value to be 0xffff by checking `(assert_hard(ChkSum==0xffff);`. The real value seems to be different and you get this assertion. Are you sure that the data sent must have 0xffff checksum? When debugging, what is the value of the sent and received checksums?

Comment: Error pops out due to its checksum is not 0xffff while it MUST NOT be 0xffff most of time. So ...I ask again: is this assert_hard required?

Comment: @nevilad in output i got value of checksum 36750. Only what i need is how to calculate checksum in C# like it´s done in C++ side ...

Comment: @LouisGo the C++ code is not mine, so i can´t rewrite it. I only need right calculation in C#

Comment: So you write a client in C# which sends data to a third party server (C++ code), which code you can't change? Than simply send everytime 0xffff as checksum.

Comment: Problem is that C++ code always checks checksum for 0xffff and apparently you're not 0xffff. Try to fix your code to 0xffff and exception might be gone. You should ask your colleague or C++ code owner. I presume you should run C++ code in release mode with NDEBUG and assertion are ignored.

Comment: To be clear, it's not the fault of the C# code. It should be the problem of C++ code. And it might be missed because most of time it runs in release mode.

Comment: @LouisGo when i try 0xffff as value for checksum is all the same. I have only compiled .exe from code owner

Comment: @nevilad yes, but 0xffff is not working .. still the same error

Comment: Does your header include only UInt32 packetMark and UInt32 OPpacketIDfields?

Comment: @nevilad yes and UInt16 Length

Comment: UInt32 packetMark, UInt32 OPpacketIDfields and UInt16 Length?

Comment: i am sending all fields from OPpacketHdrS struct. Output bytes for header (in dec) is
for testing 199 199 199 199 0 0 0 0 255 255 20 0 . This is good .. chksum is set ot 0xFFFF ... but still error on assert_hard

Comment: Can you post ChkSum declaration and initialization in the server?

Comment: It looks like the checksum is just the sum of values, clipped to 16 bits, but the list of values you just posted doesn't even add up to 0xFFFF without clipping.

Comment: The server calculates the checksum only of the half of the received header and data. Can you pass sent data to get function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server calculates the checksum only of the half of the received header and data. Sent checksum should lead to calculated checksum become 0xffff.
I assume you are sending to the server CommandKeyS structure and it's size is constant. I assume ChkSum on the server is of type _int16 and initialized to 0.
I dont know C#, so replaced parts with C++ code hoping it's not too different. You can remove get function of ChKSum field and before sending the data call this function to initialize the checksum:

```
CalcChecksum( CommandKeyS* sentData )
{
  //At this point all fields in sentData, except of OPhdr.ChKSum are properly initialized.
  UInt16 accumulator = 0;

  unsafe
  {
    //Calculate checksum of the half of the data without using ChKSum.
    UInt32 chkSummedLen = sizeof( CommandKeyS )/2;
    UInt8* chkSummedEnd = ((UInt8*)sentData) + chkSummedLen;
    sentData->OPhdr.ChKSum = 0;
    for (UInt16* p = (UInt16*)sentData; p < chkSummedEnd; ++p)
    {
      accumulator += *p;
    }

    //Calculate ChKSum to make the calculated checksum be equal to 0xffff.
    sentData->OPhdr.ChKSum = 0xffff - accumulator;
  }
}
```

The way of calculating checksums your server uses is not obvious and possibly not correct, since the bottom part of the data is not checksummed.